# Getting the font metrics before the paint method id called

Tags: java, animation, graphics, fontmetrics

Hi I am creating a news ticker/ text scroller. 
I am using the following method:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Scroll1 extends JPanel{
    private int x;
    private int x2;
    private int y;
    private String text;
    final int startX=-100;
    public Scroll1(int startX)
    {
        x2=-650;
        x = 20;
        y=150;
        text= "Some Words and others, and now this must be a longer text that takes up the whole panel/ frame for this test to work   ";
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 300);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString(text, x, y);
        g.drawString(text, x2, y);
        FontMetrics fm= g.getFontMetrics(); 
        System.out.println(fm.stringWidth(text));;
    }

    public void start() throws InterruptedException{
        while(true){
            while(x<= 650){
                x++;
                x2++;
                y = getHeight()/2;
                repaint();
                Thread.sleep(10);
                if(x2>650)
                    x2=-650;
            }

            if(x>=0)
            {
                x=-650; 
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Scrolling Panel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Scroll1 scrolling = new Scroll1(-100);

        frame.getContentPane().add(scrolling);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        try {
            scrolling.start();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically it has two strings that are being drawn. One starts at the 0 position and the other starts at -650. I got the -650 number by using the font metrics inside of the paint method. The problem is that I had to hard code that number, and if I did a different string that has different metrics, it would not work. I tried making a instance variable called width that stores the font metrics, but it seems that the width is not inputted until the paint method is called. Is there anyway I can get the metrics before it starts drawing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway I can get the metrics before it starts drawing it?

Just initialize the variable in the first call to paint (or better yet, `paintComponent` - see below) - you can do this using a boolean flag, or initialize it's value to an extreme and do a check on the value.

```
int x = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
...
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if ( x == Integer.MIN_VALUE ){
        x = -g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(text);
    }
    ...
}
```

Some other tips:

1. Use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to perform animation, or be sure to dispatch Swing specific calls to the EDT using `SwingUtilities`.
2. Don't override `paint`, rather override `paintComponent` (and be sure to call the parent method `super.paintComponent(g)`)

Comment: Works great, I am continuing to use the paint method, what is wrong with that, and why shoud I use paintComponent?

Comment: `paint` does several things, one of which is calling `paintComponent`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html